# PHP match string and get the rest?

Tags: php, regex

Lets say I have the phrase: "Men improve with the years"
then if I provide a string that matches "Men improve" I want to get the rest only "with the years".
Is this possible with regex?

Comment: Please, Post code you have tried

Comment: It is not very clear what you asking. Looks like it could be done with bare string search. Try to provide clear example and exact logical description of your problem.

Comment: How about this `trim(str_replace("Men improve", "","Men improve with the years"));`

Comment: Don't forget to trim the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regex as the questioned asked, here is some code to get you started.

```
<?php 
$str = "Men improve with the years";
$regex = "/Men improve/";

echo preg_replace($regex, "", $str);
?>
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
trim(str_replace("Men improve", "","Men improve with the years"));

 //OP - with the years
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace `$needle` at the start of `$haystack` using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$needle = "Men improve";
$haystack = "Men improve with the years";

echo preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($needle).'\s*/i', "", $haystack);
```

- `/` is the [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)
- `^` [caret](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches the position before the first character in the string
- [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) escapes the `$needle`
- `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for any kind of white-space, `*` any amount of
- `i` the [ignoreCase modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) after the ending delimiter makes the pattern match case-insensitive

To match it only, if there is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) after `$needle` modify the pattern to:

```
'/^'.preg_quote($needle).'\b\s*/i'
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this type of task we will have many ways, finally we need to choose one of the method which will be suitable for our requirement, this is one my approach

```
$str = "Men improve with the years";
$substr = "Men improve ";
$result = substr($str, strlen($substr), strlen($str) - 1);
echo trim($result);
```